# Kendo UI Broken Bindings (Cascading Combos - parameterMap problems)

Tags: knockout.js, cascade-filtering, kendo-combobox

I'm using Kendo UI Combos, and knockout.  I'm trying to cascade the results of one combo to filter the data available in another.

The dataTextField value in the parent combo cannot be used as-is to filter the child combo 
data, so I'm using the parameterMap option to change it.  Unfortunately this does not seem to work, and I receive an error when binding...

```
Message: SyntaxError: Expected ':';

Bindings value: kendoComboBox: 
    {scrollable: 
        { virtual: true }
    ,filter: 'contains',
    pageable: true, 
    dataTextField: 'Description', 
    dataValueField: 'Id', 
    autoBind: false, 
    placeholder: 'Select...' ,
    cascadeFrom: 'NotifierServiceType',
    dataSource: 
        {type : 'odata',
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        filter : {field : 'LookUpType', operator : 'eq', value:15},
        transport: {    
                read: {        url: 'http://xxx/INS/services/LookUpService.svc/LookUpItems',        dataType: 'json'    } , 
                parameterMap: function(data, type) 
                    { return { filter[filters][0][field]: 'ParentId';}
                } 
            }
        }, 
    value:notifierSubDivisionId
    }
```

When the parameterMap section is removed it binds correctly, but the child combo is not filtered, as expected.

Any help whould be gratefully received.

EDIT:

Here's revised code which gets the cascading combo working:

```
parameterMap: function(data, action) { 
    var filterStem; 
    var filter; 
    filterStem = '$inlinecount=allpages&$top=100&$filter=(LookUpType+eq+15';
    if (data.filter.filters[1] === undefined){  
        filter = ')'; }
    else {
        filter = '+and+ParentId+eq+' + data.filter.filters[1].value + ')' ;
    }  
    return filterStem + filter; }}}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to amend the filter - any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used `parameterMap` before, but the syntax that you are using looks like invalid JS.  Looks like you would only have `data` and `type` variables available to you. You would also not be able to return an object literal with the dynamic property name. You would need to create an object and set it on the object, then return the object. (`var obj = {}; obj[dynamicFieldName] = 'ParentId'; return obj;`)

Comment: Thanks RP, you're right, the js syntax is wrong. Here's modified code which successfully implements the Cascading Combos where the parentid name is not the same as is used in the Parent combo.   parameterMap: function(data, action) { 
 var filterStem; 
 var filter; 
 filterStem = '$inlinecount=allpages&$top=100&$filter=(LookUpType+eq+15';
 if (data.filter.filters[1] === undefined){  
  filter = ')'; }
 else {
  filter = '+and+ParentId+eq+' + data.filter.filters[1].value + ')' ;
 }  
 return filterStem + filter; }}}

Comment: @user2208192 - Please do not post code in comment, it is very hard to read. Please post an edit in the question, better yet, post a demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry about the code, I'm not a regular poster here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try kendoUI + jaydata for oData, it's a winning combo. (disclaimer: I work for JayData). We have a demo about cascading combo here: http://jaydata.org/examples/KendoUI/cascadingcombobox.html
For a simple cascading combo you'll only need a few lines of custom javascript code.

```
$data.initService(url)
.then(function (remoteDB) {
    $("#categories").kendoComboBox({
      placeholder: "Select category...",
      dataTextField: "Category_Name",
      dataValueField: "Category_ID",
      dataSource: remoteDB.Categories.asKendoDataSource()
    });

    var products = $("#products").kendoComboBox({
      autoBind: false,
      cascadeFrom: "categories",
      placeholder: "Select product...",
      dataTextField: "Product_Name",
      dataValueField: "Product_ID",
      dataSource: remoteDB.Products.asKendoDataSource()
    }).data("kendoComboBox");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't see how this approach helps me 'switch' the field id which is used to filter the odata? Am I missing something here?

Comment: you can switch the field easily, something like this (it is not jaydata specific but kendoui datasource thing but with jaydata you don't need to do anything else)
    var datasource = remoteDB.Categories.asKendoDatasource();
    ... use it with kendo widget ...
    ... then later ...
   datasource.filter({ field: "Price", operator: "lt", value: 3 });
   ... or ...
   datasource.filter({ field: "Name", operator: "eq", value: 'blah' });